# Separate a string using regex based on an array of matchs

Tags: python, regex

I need to separate the brand from the model of a named car using a array of brands to match. I tried something like that:

```
import re

carName = "Fiat Strada Working 1.4 CS"

brands = ["Acura","Alfa Romeo","Aston Martin","Audi","Bentley","BMW","Bugatti","Buick","Cadillac","Chevrolet",
"Chrysler","Citroen","Dodge","Ferrari","Fiat","Ford","Geely","General Motors","GMC","Honda","Hyundai",
"Mercedes-Benz","Renault"]

carBrand = re.split("'|'.join(brands)|[^a-zA-Z ]+", carName)

print(carBrand)
```

But got this: ['Fiat Strada Working ', None, ' CS']

I need this: ['Fiat' , 'Strada Working 1.4 CS']

I'm having trouble finding the right regex to separate right after the join of brands.

Comment: If you split you loose the separator, so with this method `Fiat` will be gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is completely wrong and you use the wrong re-method:

```
import re

carName = "Fiat Strada Working 1.4 CS"

brands = ["Acura","Alfa Romeo","Aston Martin","Audi","Bentley","BMW","Bugatti","Buick","Cadillac","Chevrolet",
"Chrysler","Citroen","Dodge","Ferrari","Fiat","Ford","Geely","General Motors","GMC","Honda","Hyundai",
"Mercedes-Benz","Renault"]

carBrand = list( re.match(f"({'|'.join(brands)})(.*)", carName).groups() )

print(carBrand)
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved. Using list with re.match you can create separate elements in the list by applying regex in each one. So you create a group for the brands regex, and other for everything that comes after with ( . * )